# Difference between Button.Click() and Button.Press()

Tags: automated-testing, ranorex

We observe differences using `button.Click()` versus `button.Press()` when we run automated tests for our Java application (Windows, desktop).

The [documentation for Button](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/T_Ranorex_Button.htm) does not tell so much:

`Click()`:

> Clicks on the adapter with the left mouse button.

and (not applicable for our application)

> If this method is invoked on a mobile element, Touch() will be called internally.

`Press()`:

> Presses the button.

What is the difference between those two methods? Any guideline when to use which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an official answer, but the difference is mainly in 2 things:

1. continuation of the Ranorex test script
2. the number of events fired

Conclusion: `Click()` is closer to real user interaction, `Press()` is faster and more robust as long as it is sufficient for your automation.

Regarding 1., I have observed:

`Click()` immediately continues the Ranorex script execution as opposed to  `Press()` which waits until the code of the event handler has completed.

This can e.g. have the following impact: if a message box is opened synchronously when the button is "clicked", and you use `Press()` in the Ranorex script, then you cannot answer the message box from the Ranorex script in the next step. Your test case will hang.

Regarding 2., I have observed:

`Click()`:

- Paint (may occur multiple times in different order)
- MouseEnter
- MouseMove (may occur multiple times)
- MouseDown
- MouseHover
- Click
- MouseClick
- MouseUp
- MouseMove (may occur multiple times)

`Press()`:

- Paint (may occur multiple times in different order)
- Click